# Is there a way to get table entry id ahead of insertion?

Tags: asp.net, sql

I am trying to save an entry to database and there is an image file that goes along with it(uploaded into a folder). I want the image file path to be saved in the database also, but, the problem is, I want the file name to use the id of the entry (PhotoId), to ensure that the image file name will always be unique. I have this code which does not really work because PhotoId has not yet been generated, and so saved images all have file names of 0.jpg.

Is there anyway I can predict the id for sure, so I can put it into the filename field of the database entry? It's a catch 22 otherwise.

```
            if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + photo.ClientId)))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/") + photo.ClientId);
            }
            var FileExt = Path.GetExtension(photo.File.FileName);
            var FilePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + photo.ClientId), photo.PhotoId.ToString()) + FileExt;
            photo.File.SaveAs(FilePath);
            var ThumbFilePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + photo.ClientId),photo.PhotoId.ToString() + "_thumbnail") + FileExt;
            PhotoTools.MakeThumbnail(FilePath, ThumbFilePath, 0.15);

            //Finally update database
            photo.FilePath = FilePath;
            db.Photos.Add(photo);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Create");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, you would save the database record, get the ID, then save the filename. And if you must, update the record with the path.

But if the path is always the same, except for the ID, why save it to the database?

Comment: My issue was that the extension can vary, however I think I figured it out; I will simply store the extension, which I can figure out before storing entry to database.

Answer (score 0):

Select the count of table records and add +1 to that.
You can get.

Better to generate a `GUID` or Add `DateTime`

Comment: Careful though, if an AutoIncrement ID is used, and the last record or any record was deleted, the "count" will not predict the correct next ID.

Comment: Also not safe if, you know, more than one person is using the site. Which tends to be quite common for modern systems.